# Cannot read properties of undefined for service error when passing method as parameter from service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to pass a function of service as a parameter to another function. Whenever, I try to pass function as parameter and it executes, then I get error 'Cannot read properties of undefined myService'

When I call this.myService.method() individually. It's completely working fine. There is no problem. What could be the issue?

My ts file:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService)

 function1(): void {
        this.function2(this.myService.method)
    } 

function2(f: Function)
{
    f();

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full details : [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used)

**Solution 1** : bind `this` to service context on initialization

```
function1(): void {
    this.function2(this.myService.method.bind(this));
    //or this.function2(() => this.myService.method());
}
```

**Solution 2** : bind `this` to service context before call

```
function2(f: Function)
{
    f.bind(this)();
}
```